# Encapsulated div positioning

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve the following effect using HTML & CSS:

---

### Printscreen

[image]

---

However, I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.
The current state is the following:

```
<div class="post"><!-- Posts are just divs with a white background -->
    <div class="post-header">
        <div class="left">Som Text</div>

        <div class="center">
            <img src="pseudo" class="center" />
        </div>

        <div class="right">Som Text</div>
    </div>

    <p class="title">Som Text</p>
</div>
```

Then, I'm simply doing a `margin-top:-66px;` on `div.post div.post-header`.
This is probably not what one should do.

Can you give me an idea on how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can Try Position-relative thing also, for this make `post` class `position:relative` and other class as `position:absolute` and set them where u want

Comment: I don't think `position:relative;` is right. Because the content of the post (the title) goes up. So I tried setting the relative position only on the image, which is good. The text stays the same. The only thing now is that its not centred anymore. How can I centre the div now?

Comment: make `center` class `position:relative` and image `position:absolute` align="center" to the image div it will work correctly

Comment: I added `left:0; right:0;` and now it works with `margin:auto;`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

a print screen or just a margin-top property won't do any good, since the screenshot is not displayed here too. 
can u give me the link to see the live preview of the page

Comment: That's ok :) The site isn't online yet, I would't have been able to show it to you.

Comment: ok then can you send another screen shot and also send css for post post-header left center right title classes you used there ?

Comment: It seems there were some problems with the proxy server I use, any way, now that I see the image, I see there s some positioning, 
U'r using some float attribute I guess for the left and right and center classes, (if not u should use, and you have to make different tags for them let me see what can I do for you with this lack of info and no access to what you working on

Comment: If u were able to get a live preview I'd be able to help you then ;)
but try using float attribute and position ing attributes as our friend mentioned above

Comment: Sorry I can't. It is working, the question is just if it's the right approach.

Comment: margin-top is good enough to reach this, you can try givin the attribute position:relative; top:66px; to the div.post div.post-header

I guess it works, if didn't try + or - values for the top attribute
that's one easy way to solve the problem (note; when a tag is a relative position, the parent tag must either be havin no positionin at all all the posiion of the parent tag should be static or absolute)

Comment: Yes it is a working approach but not the best, in other words ;)

Comment: haha I know it's working ;) I want to know the BEST approach :D

Comment: It's going to be sold in a template, that's why it needs to be perfect

Comment: wish you good luck with the template ;) , the best approach is to put those 4 elements (3 text and 1 image) in to div tag, give the parrent element a width, and use float and position attribute for the rest of the elements there. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Take a look @ soms answer. It's not much, but it pointed me into the right direction. I set only the imageWrapper to `position:relative;` and then I was able to move only that one to the top. I think it's a pretty good solution. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: you know some how it's just the style of working around with css, although technically there are some attributes that are logically better to use, but it depends on you on which one to use, the more you practice around using them, the wiser you'll get in using which one ;)
you've to figure it out your self ;)

Comment: The HTML Logic is perfect, because all of the content is in the post div. I think that's the most important part.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar on my site. Feel free to visit http://robertfauver.com/